# Iframe resize on content change

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have this code:

```
<iframe id='iFrame' src='iframe.php' onload='javascript:iFrameResize(this);'></iframe>
```

```js
function iFrameResize(obj) 
{
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

It works fine when I first load the page. But, when I select something in the iframe and the content height is larger than the iframe height, the iframe does not resized.

Is there a way to always resize the iframe when it's content changes(the iframe location does not change, content is added/modified with javascript)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) onload triggers on load and not on click of something 2) `javascript:` pseudo protocol/label is unnecessary

Comment: I know that, i need a way to resize the iframe on content update without reloading the src url.

Comment: Are the frame and the top document in the same domain (thus "accessible" via JS in either direction)?

Comment: yes, they are on the same domain.